# Best way to create function that calls itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way to create a function that calls itself based on condition? For example, I have a dictionary variable say "table" that contains text(value) meta data(key) and another variable that contains comparison text say "line". I need to write a program that will take data from line and match it with "table" values. If the match is successful then it should output "table-key+line" else it will remove the last word from "line" and perform the same operation. Example table variable and line variable is given below :

**Table Variable :**

```
{'[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.768, Font Weight : 0.0]': 'Additions based on tax 
positions related to the They believe that it is reasonably possible that approximately $40 million of 
its unrecognized tax benefits may be recognized by the end of 2019 as a result of a lapse of the statute 
of limitations or resolution with the tax authorities.', [Base Font : IOFOEO+Imago-Book, Font Size : 6.84, 
Font Weight : 0.0]': 'Additions based on tax positions related to prior'}
```

**Line Variable :**

```
Additions based on tax positions related to the Additions based on tax positions related to prior Bunge 
believes that it is reasonably possible that approximately $40 million of its unrecognized tax benefits 
may be recognized by the end of 2019 as a result of a lapse of the statute of limitations or resolution 
with the tax authorities.
```

**My Logic : This logic does not give expected output**

```
with open("myfile1.txt","r", encoding='utf-8') as f, open("myfile2.txt","w") as f1:
for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        words = " ".join(line.split())
        for i in table:
            if words in table[i]:
                f1.write(i+line)
                break
            else:
                pass
        else:
            line_split = line.split()
            remaining_itemlist = []
            while len(line_split)>0:
                for i in table:
                    words = " ".join(line_split[:len(line_split)])
                    if words in table[i]:
                        f1.write(i+words)
                        new_word = words.split()
                        for i in range(len(new_word)):
                            line_split.pop(0)
                        for i in table:
                            if " ".join(remaining_itemlist) in table[i]:
                                f1.write(i+" ".join(remaining_itemlist))
                                break
                        break
                    else:
                        pass
                else:
                    remaining_itemlist.insert(0, line_split.pop(-1))
    else:
        f1.write(line)
```

**My Output :**

```
[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.768, Font Weight : 0.0]Additions based on tax positions 
related to the Additions based on tax positions related to prior They believe that it is reasonably 
possible that approximately $40 million of its unrecognized tax benefits may be recognized by the end of 
2019 as a result of a lapse of the statute of limitations or resolution with the tax authorities.
```

**Expected Output :**

```
[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.768, Font Weight : 0.0]Additions based on tax positions 
related to the [Base Font : IOFOEO+Imago-Book, Font Size : 6.84, Font Weight : 0.0]Additions based on tax 
positions related to prior [Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.768, Font Weight : 0.0]They believe that it 
is reasonably possible that approximately $40 million of its unrecognized tax benefits may be recognized 
by the end of 2019 as a result of a lapse of the statute of limitations or resolution with the tax authorities.
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are asking? A "function that calls itself" (commonly called "recursive function") literally just does that, i.e. it calls itself. That is just ``def name(...): name(...)``. There are not really any variations of this, so there is no "best way", just one obvious one. What variants do you consider that could have a "best" solution, and what is your criteria for being "best"?

Comment: I have used best way in context of given example. I was not able to call a function recursively to generate expected output. I am pretty sure that only change required in given code is to call function recursively. However, since I am new to programming, i am not sure. I have called the function as you have mentioned but still I am far from getting expected output. Is there any other possible solution to get expected output?

Comment: The code shown is a slightly malformed collection of statements. Can you clarify what part you intend to turn into a recursive function?

Comment: Line number 23. I think there will be else statement which should call function to get desired output. Can you please tell which part you feel is malformed? Is there any line of code we can skip or do better?

Answer (score 0):

I've Written Some easy code which could be replaced with yours with necessary edits

```
line='there is some line which is needed to be checked'

your_dict = {'key1':'there is some line','key2':'it is not','key3':'not even this'}

def check_the_match(line):
    flag=0
    for k in your_dict.keys():
        if line in your_dict[k]:
            flag=1
            print(k+line)
        
    if flag==0:
        print('Checking again')
        new_line = " ".join(line.split()[:-1])
        check_the_match(new_line)

check_the_match(line)
```

I got the below Output:

```
Checking again
Checking again
Checking again
Checking again
Checking again
Checking again
key1there is some line
```

Comment: Hi @Abhinav, your code also has some flaws and it does not suffice my need. Can you modify your input or just use mine and then try your code. However, your code does give me an idea on how to call function from itself.

Comment: I created it Just to Give an Idea :)   .. Thats Why I wrote "necessary edits"

Comment: Agree, I did make some modification to it. It did not help. Problem is, to include complexities, my code has gotten that lengthy. That is why I am seeking help here.

Answer (score 0):

I am Adding another piece of code:
Please make sure you increase the recursion limit as python has low recursion limit.
You can use sys library to play with recursion limit
I made it based on my understanding of the problem, Apologies is any error

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)

dictionary={
                '[Base Font : IOHLGA+Trebuchet, Font Size : 3.768, Font Weight : 0.0]': 'Additions based on tax positions related to the They believe that it is reasonably possible that approximately $40 million of its unrecognized tax benefits may be recognized by the end of 2019 as a result of a lapse of the statute of limitations or resolution with the tax authorities.',
                '[Base Font : IOFOEO+Imago-Book, Font Size : 6.84, Font Weight : 0.0]': 'Additions based on tax positions related to prior'
            }


line ='Additions based on tax positions related to the Additions based on tax positions related to prior Bunge believes that it is reasonably possible that approximately $40 million of its unrecognized tax benefits may be recognized by the end of 2019 as a result of a lapse of the statute of limitations or resolution with the tax authorities.'


                           
def check_the_match(line):
    
    for k in dictionary.keys():
        if line in dictionary[k]:
            print(k+dictionary[k])
     
    # trimming the line
    new_line = " ".join(line.split(' ')[:-1])
    
    
    if len(new_line.split(' ')[:-1])>1:
        
        check_the_match(new_line)

        
check_the_match(line)
```